# Two array binding in one foreach loop in knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

Please look at my view model below:

```
viewModel = [
 {
  StudentName : 'Ronald',
  Reviews : [ '3/5', '2/5', '4/5'],
  TeacherNames : [ 'Nema', 'Sarah', 'Vilson']
  },
 {
  StudentName : 'Chris',
  Reviews : [ '4.5/5', '2.5/5', '3.5/5'],
  TeacherNames : [ 'Nema', 'Sarah', 'Vilson']
 }
]
```

In below HTML I am trying to display Reviews in nested foreach structure. Reviews display as per expectation. but how can I place `TeacherNames` along with that single review? I have put the `TeacherNames[$index]`, but it doesn't work.

**Note 1:** Number of elements in both the array(i.e. Reviews and TeacherNames) will be same.

**Note 2:** I don't want to change the structure of this JSON model, something like putting extra variable and placing both the parameters in one array.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:viewModel">
    <span data-bind="text: StudentName"></span>
     <ul data-bind="foreach:Reviews">
       <li>
         <a href="#" data-bind="text:$data">Inbox </a>
         <span class="ui-li-count" data-bind="text:TeacherNames[$index]">123</span>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Please check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RCnVR/) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it like this: `$index` is the observable, and `$index()` is the value of the observable.  You need to give the TeacherNames array the number, not the observable.

Use

`<span data-bind="text:$parent.TeacherNames[$index()]" >123</span>`

instead of

`<span data-bind="text:$parent.TeacherNames[$index]" >123</span>`

to access the value `$index()`.

I made a copy of your [fiddle with the changes applied](http://jsfiddle.net/RoyalleBlue/RCnVR/1/).

Also, thank you to [Calvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372720/calvin), who just used this example to help me on the same question in a different format.

Answer (score 2):

RoyalleBlue's answer is correct when using just the `foreach` binding. But using my [Repeat](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding will make your binding code much cleaner:

```
<ul>
  <li data-bind="repeat:Reviews.length">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text:Reviews[$index]"></a>
    <span data-bind="text:TeacherNames[$index]"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/p2kHU/

Comment: This solution works as expected, but I guess @RoyalleBlue has better solution in terms basic way of implementation. Thanks for help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your property is called TeacherNames, but you are calling it as TeacherName.

Also, it is on the parent object, so try:

```
data-bind="text:$parent.TeacherNames[$index()]"
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the property name. Still it doesn't work, please help.

Comment: Below error I am getting:

Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: TeacherNames is not defined;
Bindings value: text:TeacherNames[$index] .

I tried putting below binding also:
data-bind="text:$parent.TeacherNames[$index]" .
In this case, it doesn't show any error, it is just not showing data as expected.

Comment: As I mentioned in above comment, I tried this also : data-bind="text:$parent.TeacherNames[$index]" , it doesn't show any error, it is just not showing data as expected.

Comment: This answer misses the fact that `$index` is an observable.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
The scope (context) is wrong. You can access TeacherNames with $parent or $root.

Changed:

```
<span data-bind="text:TeacherNames[$index()]" >123</span>
```

To:

```
<span data-bind="text:$parent.TeacherNames[$index()]" >123</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calvinslusarski/7xuKX/2/

Comment: This answer misses the fact that `$index` is an observable.